# Java Heap Space error in jar file

Tags: java, swing, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I've read couple of post about the java heap space out of memory error. I'm using Java Swing and getting an error 'java heap space'. Then I tried to run this jar from command prompt using this command:

```
java -Xmx128m -Xms128m -jar jedit.jar
```

The jar runs very well. But now the problem is that how can run this jar file by double click?  I think I have to write something in `META-INF`. But I don't know what to write. Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of providing VM parameters in the MANIFEST file, you cannot do that. That is not a possibility.

Rather you can use a executable wrapper which allows you to provide VM arguments and other startup parameters like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a Swing app., the best route to get extra memory (& a whole heap of other goodies) would be to deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, **RAM** etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

---

JWS provides a way to specify memory requirements in the JNLP based launch file. So you could provide versions of the program with different memory assignments, using the same Jars but with different launch files.